# RecyclerView not working while fetching data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The `RecyclerView` is not working while fetching data from `Firebase`. The Android monitor says the problem is in `fetchData()` function in FirebaseHelper.java.

FirebaseHelper.java

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
DatabaseReference db;
ArrayList<SaveData> sd=new ArrayList<>();

//pass database reference
public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db){
    this.db=db;
}

//read by hooking onto database operation callbacks
public ArrayList<SaveData>retrieve(){
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return sd;
}

//implement fetch data and fill arraylist

public void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    sd.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        SaveData saves=ds.getValue(SaveData.class);
        sd.add(saves);
    }
}
```

code for RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
Context c;
ArrayList<SaveData>sd;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<SaveData> sd) {
    this.c = c;
    this.sd = sd;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.ItemnameTxt.setText(sd.get(position).getName());
    holder.BrandNameTxt.setText(sd.get(position).getBrand_Name());
    holder.CaloriesTxt.setText((int) sd.get(position).getSave_Calories());
    holder.FatTxt.setText((int) sd.get(position).getSave_Fat());
    holder.Servingtxt.setText(sd.get(position).getServing_Size());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sd.size();
}
```

Savedata model

```
public class SaveData {
String name,brand_Name,serving_Size;
double save_calories,save_fat;

public SaveData(String name, String brand_Name, String serving_Size, double save_calories, double save_fat) {
    this.name = name;
    this.brand_Name = brand_Name;
    this.serving_Size = serving_Size;
    this.save_calories = save_calories;
    this.save_fat = save_fat;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBrand_Name() {
    return brand_Name;
}

public void setBrand_Name(String brand_Name) {
    this.brand_Name = brand_Name;
}

public String getServing_Size() {
    return serving_Size;
}

public void setServing_Size(String serving_Size) {
    this.serving_Size = serving_Size;
}

public double getSave_calories() {
    return save_calories;
}

public void setSave_calories(double save_calories) {
    this.save_calories = save_calories;
}

public double getSave_fat() {
    return save_fat;
}

public void setSave_fat(double save_fat) {
    this.save_fat = save_fat;
}
```

Errors are as follows

```
Process: nutritionapp.listview.bio.ayushsharma.nutritionapp, PID: 3105

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type 
java.lang.String to type Model.SaveData

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)

at data.FirebaseHelper.fetchData(FirebaseHelper.java:61)

at data.FirebaseHelper$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseHelper.java:30)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at 


com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: @i_m_mahii: please don't use quote devices for filenames that introduce code material. They are not actually quotes. Ordinary paragraph text is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving data from snap shot in wrong way. Try this..

```
public ArrayList<SaveData>retrieve(){
  sd.clear();
  db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        SaveData saves=dataSnapshot.getValue(SaveData.class);
        sd.add(saves);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
return sd;
}
```

i hope it helps.